# Refs uses in Constructors when collection updates?

Tags: c#, constructor

I have constructor of some service:

```
public Ctor(List<Items> items)
{
    _items = items;
}

public void Work()
{
    if(_items.Count() > 5) 
    //do some work
}
```

`Work` method will be called time by time.
So, if outside of the object I change `items` - what happens?
Will `_items.Count()` change?

Because at this current version i use this:

```
public void Work()
{
     if(StaticClass.Items.Count() > 5)
    //do some work
}
```

Where `StaticClass.Items` updates when outside items collection changes.
So, if i make this:

```
 var service = new Constructor(StaticClass.Items);
```

And then I update `StaticClass.Items` elements -

Can I use actual `_items.Count()` value when `Work` method calls (by some timer) or should I use `ref` keyword?

Comment: Try it and find out.  You've already written the code.  See what happens when you run it.

Comment: If you don't know _precisely_ why you're passing something by `ref`, you probably don't need it.  It's a _very_ rare situation that requires it.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  If the number of items in a collection changes, then the result of calling `.Count()` on that collection would also change.  `.Count()` returns the current number of items.  What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: I mean, what happens,that number of items changes?

Comment: @AdmiralLand Why are you asking us when you already have the code written?  Run the code and find out.

Comment: If you modify collection then result of `Count()` will reflect it. It's a method which returns appropriate property of underlying collection (e.g. in case of array it's `Length` of it). Problem will only arise in multi-thread environment, if to example you call `Count()` before or during modification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass a collection through the constructor like your example, you actually pass the reference of the list. `ref` keyword is, in most cases, for `struct` and value type parameters.

Doing this:

```
public myClass(IEnumerable<MyOtherClass> pMyItems)
{
    _items = pMyItems;
}
```

will be the same as

```
public myClass(ref IEnumerable<MyOtherClass> pMyItems)
{
    _items = pMyItems;
}
```

because IEnumerable or List, in your case, are usually references types.

So to answer your question: whether you use `ref` or no, in your situation, modifying the collection outside of the instanciated object will modify the collection in the instanciated object: **it is the same instance**, referenced at both places.

Here's the [MSDN entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) for the `ref` keyword in C# for more infos.